# Arduino led not blinking

Tags: arduino-uno, led

```
#include <Arduino.h>

void setup()
 {
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
 }
void loop()
{
 digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
 delay(1);
 digitalWrite(13, LOW);
 delay(1);
}
```

I am trying to make an led glow for one second to glow and then go off but nothing happens

Comment: how did produce a wrong version of the most basic Arduino example? https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples/Blink

Comment: Your first step when facing such a problem is to read the documentation. You have 3 functions in your code, which as read in a short time, less than 5 minutes. You would have found the `delay()` expects the interval in milliseconds. Please do so the enxt time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <Arduino.h>

void setup()
 {
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
 }
void loop()
{
 digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
 delay(1000);
 digitalWrite(13, LOW);
 delay(1000);
}
```

The problem with your code is that the delay function works in milliseconds and not seconds . 1sec = 1000ms .

Comment: thanks it is working now

Comment: what is next? The "Bare Minimum" example without loop()?

Comment: True but just go a little easy in the newbie

Comment: @Juraj: The Bare Minimum Blink (https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoUno#open-your-first-sketch ) works without the line `#include <Arduino.h>`

Comment: I use platform io for programing so in that it is important to include arduino.h maybe the person who asked is also using platform io or something similar

Answer (score 1):

by increasing the delay value, you can visualize it better.

```
{

 digitalWrite(13, HIGH);

 delay(2000);

 digitalWrite(13, LOW);

 delay(1000);

}
```